# What pattern to use with aspnet mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvp, new-project

I always used asp.net webforms with the MVP pattern, it works great for what I need, I basically create a project where all my business rules reside, validation etc... and I then implement my views in the webforms project.

Now we're starting to use asp.net MVC and using the MVP patter doesn't make much sense, right? So what could be a good approach to create a scalable and testable project using MVC that won't make me create my data objects and do validation on the controllers. I don' want to have the same code in different places...

If a web user wants to update his/her profile on the site, there would be some validation rules for when a submit button is pushed, like email address cannot be empty, must be valid and must not exist in the database.

These same rules should be applied if I try to update his profile using the internal admin section without having to duplicate the code there...

If you can point me to a good sample project that deals with this would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason some people might find this question confusing is that MVC is a pattern.  In the same way that you wouldn't ask: "What pattern do I use with the Singleton pattern?" it does not make sense to ask what pattern to use with MVC.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the MVC pattern with ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

The [NerdDinner](https://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) tutorial is a pretty detailed example for MVC, you can also get a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470643188) that includes the tutorial (you might want to wait for the version that covers [ASP.Net MVC 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583)).  There are plenty of resources on Microsoft's [ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site.

You can always consult [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

ASP .NET MVC was built with the [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern in mind.  That would be the pattern you'd want to use.

In addition to the resources magnifico provided, I know others have recommended the some other tutorials.  I don't know if these have been updated to the latest version of the framework, but they should still serve as decent beginners.

[MVC Storefront series](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/)

[MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

Also the Microsoft Patterns & Practices group recently released [Project Silk](http://silk.codeplex.com/) which gets into more advanced techniques involving a lot of AJAX management of the UI.  There's interesting stuff there.